# Storing an image created with imagecopy(), using Laravel's store()

Tags: php, laravel, image, gd

I have an image created using php's imagecopy(), to add a watermark:

```
imagecopy($base, $stamp, imagesx($base) - $sx, imagesy($base) - $sy, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
```

This is lifted straight from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) and works fine. It creates my image with $base and if I was to set my headers to jpeg I could output the image in my browser.

However the next step is to store it using Laravel. I can do it manually using

```
imagejpeg($base,$storagePath)
```

Again, this works fine. However, what I would really like is to take my $base, and store it the right way, eg

```
$base->store('mydirectory');
```

But this is not possible, as $base just isn't giving me something that store() is meant to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I worked this out in the end, I needed to get the image data using output buffering, then use Storage::put, which can store raw data.

So making sure I'm using storage:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Then store the image

```
// prepare a path
$filename = uniqid().'.jpeg';
$path = 'images/'.$filename;

// output buffering so you can load imagejpeg() created raw data as a variable
ob_start();
imagejpeg($base);
$image_contents = ob_get_clean();

// put it in storage using Laravel
Storage::put($path, $image_contents);
```